Wordpress Use Javascript click on button does not work
I have a form to set a CSS between 2 options, I add another php files for create a banner, when I click on the button switch I can change the css, the problem is that when Wordpress option is selected in the form the button to switch works perfectly but when I select on the form Wooster it doesn't work anymore :
    <?php
/**
 * Class used to manage the display of the content of the settings
 */
class WoosterPartnerSettings
{
    /**
     * Hook to display the contents of the 'Settings' menu if the license is valid
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (get_option('partner_license') && get_option('partner_license') != '') {
            add_action('tab_content_settings', array($this, 'wooster_partner_settings'));
            add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'display_style'));
            add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_style'));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Allows you to display the form to choose the style sheet to display
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function wooster_partner_settings()
    {
?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1><?php echo __('Réglages Wooster', 'wooster-partner'); ?></h1>
            <hr class="line">

            <form method="post" action="options.php">
                <?php settings_fields('wooster-settings-group'); ?>
                <?php do_settings_sections('wooster-settings-group'); ?>

                <p class="parag"><?php echo __('Le plugin Compagnon propose deux styles d’affichage :', 'wooster-partner'); ?></p>

                <label for="style_wordpress">
                    <input type="radio" id="style_wordpress" name="wooster_style" value="compagnon-wp.css" <?php checked(get_option('wooster_style'), 'compagnon-wp.css'); ?>>
                    <?php echo __('Style WordPress', 'wooster-partner'); ?>
                </label>

                <label for="style_wooster">
                    <input type="radio" id="style_wooster" name="wooster_style" value="compagnon-wooster.css" <?php checked(get_option('wooster_style'), 'compagnon-wooster.css'); ?>>
                    <?php echo __('Style Wooster', 'wooster-partner'); ?>
                </label><br>

                <input type="submit" class="wooster-button" value="<?php echo __('Enregistrer les modifications', 'wooster-partner') ?>">
            </form>
        </div>
<?php
    }


    /**
     * Registers the setting for the Wooster plugin style
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function display_style()
    {
        register_setting('wooster-settings-group', 'wooster_style');
    }

    /**
     * Enqueues the selected style for Wooster plugin settings page
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function enqueue_style()
    {
        if (is_admin()) {
            if (isset($_GET['page']) && strpos($_GET['page'], 'wooster') === 0) {
                $selected_style = get_option('wooster_style', 'compagnon-wp.css'); // default style
                wp_enqueue_style('wooster-custom-style', plugins_url('wooster-partner/assets/css/' . $selected_style));
            }
        }
    }
    }
new WoosterPartnerSettings();

<?php

/**
 * WoosterBanner class
 * It creates  a banner for the Wooster plugin
 *
 * @package Wooster
 */
class WoosterBanner
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['page']) && in_array($_GET['page'], ['wooster', 'wooster-followup', 'wooster-licences', 'wooster-compagnon', 'wooster-customers', 'wooster-partner', 'wooster-settings', 'wooster-setup']) && is_admin()) {
            add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_styles'));
            //add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_styles'));
            add_action('in_admin_header', array($this, 'wooster_header_section'));
            add_action('admin_footer', array($this, 'add_switch_style_button'));
        }
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_styles')); // for the front page

    }
    /**
     * Adds the banner to the top of the Wooster plugin settings page
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function wooster_header_section()
    {
?>
        <div id="top-bar-banner">
            <div class="wooster-banner">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="<?php echo plugins_url('assets/img/logo.png', __DIR__); ?>" alt="Logo">
                </div>
                <div class="actions">
                <div id="wooster-activity-panel" class="wooster-layout__activity-panel" aria-labelledby="activity-panel-header_73">

                <div role="tablist" aria-orientation="horizontal" class="wooster-layout__activity-panel-tabs">

                    <button type="button" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="activity-panel-previewStore" id="switch-style" class="components-button wooster-layout__activity-panel-tab"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><!--!Font Awesome Free 6.5.2 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.-->
                            <path d="M0 224c0 17.7 14.3 32 32 32s32-14.3 32-32c0-53 43-96 96-96H320v32c0 12.9 7.8 24.6 19.8 29.6s25.7 2.2 34.9-6.9l64-64c12.5-12.5 12.5-32.8 0-45.3l-64-64c-9.2-9.2-22.9-11.9-34.9-6.9S320 19.1 320 32V64H160C71.6 64 0 135.6 0 224zm512 64c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32s-32 14.3-32 32c0 53-43 96-96 96H192V352c0-12.9-7.8-24.6-19.8-29.6s-25.7-2.2-34.9 6.9l-64 64c-12.5 12.5-12.5 32.8 0 45.3l64 64c9.2 9.2 22.9 11.9 34.9 6.9s19.8-16.6 19.8-29.6V448H352c88.4 0 160-71.6 160-160z" />
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="activity-panel-previewStore" id="user-icon" class="components-button wooster-layout__activity-panel-tab"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><!--!Font Awesome Free 6.5.2 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.-->
                            <path d="M304 128a80 80 0 1 0 -160 0 80 80 0 1 0 160 0zM96 128a128 128 0 1 1 256 0A128 128 0 1 1 96 128zM49.3 464H398.7c-8.9-63.3-63.3-112-129-112H178.3c-65.7 0-120.1 48.7-129 112zM0 482.3C0 383.8 79.8 304 178.3 304h91.4C368.2 304 448 383.8 448 482.3c0 16.4-13.3 29.7-29.7 29.7H29.7C13.3 512 0 498.7 0 482.3z" />
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="activity-panel-help" id="help-icon" class="components-button wooster-layout__activity-panel-tab"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
                            <path d="M12 4.75a7.25 7.25 0 100 14.5 7.25 7.25 0 000-14.5zM3.25 12a8.75 8.75 0 1117.5 0 8.75 8.75 0 01-17.5 0zM12 8.75a1.5 1.5 0 01.167 2.99c-.465.052-.917.44-.917 1.01V14h1.5v-.845A3 3 0 109 10.25h1.5a1.5 1.5 0 011.5-1.5zM11.25 15v1.5h1.5V15h-1.5z"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
    </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
    /**
     * Registers the setting for the Wooster plugin style switch button
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function add_switch_style_button()
    {
    ?>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var toggleStyleBtn = document.getElementById('switch-style');
            var currentStyle = localStorage.getItem('wooster_style') || '<?php echo get_option('wooster_style', 'compagnon-wp.css'); ?>';
            //console.log('Style récupéré depuis localStorage :', currentStyle); // Instruction de débogage
            toggleStyleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                currentStyle = currentStyle === 'compagnon-wp.css' ? 'compagnon-wooster.css' : 'compagnon-wp.css';
                changeStyle(currentStyle);
            });


            function changeStyle(styleName) {
                var styleElement = document.getElementById('wooster-custom-style');
                if (!styleElement) {
                    styleElement = document.createElement('link');
                    styleElement.id = 'wooster-custom-style';
                    styleElement.rel = 'stylesheet';
                    document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
                }
                styleElement.href = '<?php echo plugins_url('wooster-partner/assets/css/'); ?>' + styleName;
                localStorage.setItem('wooster_style', styleName);
                //console.log('Style défini dans localStorage :', styleName); // Instruction de débogage
            }

            // Charger le style initial
            changeStyle(currentStyle);


            });
        </script>
<?php
    }


    /**
     * Enqueues the selected style for Wooster plugin settings page
     *
     * @return void
     */




     public function enqueue_styles()
     {
         $selected_style = get_option('wooster_style', 'compagnon-wp.css'); // Style par défaut

         wp_enqueue_style('wooster-custom-style', plugins_url('wooster-partner/assets/css/' . $selected_style));

         // Enfiler d'autres styles nécessaires
         wp_enqueue_style('wooster-banner', plugins_url('assets/css/banner.css', __DIR__));
         wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css', array(), '5.15.4');
         wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // Bibliothèque JavaScript

         // Localiser votre script
         wp_localize_script('switch-style', 'switch_style_vars', array(
             'wooster_style_url' => plugins_url("wooster-partner/assets/css/compagnon-wooster.css"),
             'wp_style_url' => plugins_url("wooster-partner/assets/css/compagnon-wp.css"),
         ));

         // Enfiler votre script
         wp_enqueue_script('switch-style');
     }



}

new WoosterBanner();

I tried to enqueue dequeue but as I already put a condition in the script , it should not be necessary. I can't also enqueue and dequeue as the same time
